# Can I copy the value of pointer of interface with tags in golang with unknown type

Tags: go, pointers, reflect

**Can I copy the value of pointer of interface with tags in golang with unknown type**

I have a function called "CensorPayload" it will receive a pointer and Unmarshal and censor some field that have tag called "censored" but I don't want to update value in argument called "target" that mean I have to copy the value of target to new interface{}. I try many way such as reflect.New but the tag does not pass through  Unmarshal or Do function.

```
type HelloWorld struct {
    Hello string `json:"hello"`
    Password string `json:"password" censored:"*****"`
}

a := HelloWorld{}

CensorPayload(&a, `{"hello": "world", "password": "12345"}`)

func CensorPayload(target interface{}, payload string) (string, error) {
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(payload), target)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    err = Do(target)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    censoredPayload, err := json.Marshal(target)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(censoredPayload), nil
}
```

Comment: are you trying to change the json field name of Password from `password` to `censored`

Comment: To skip it from being parsed by the package, you can set  `json:"-"`  as the annotation to the Password field - if this is not the use case, can you add more details?

Comment: Thank for comment but I sill wanna Marshal it for some usecase 

Comment: Maybe (just maybe) you could get around the problem by not completely eliminating the password field but "mangling" it? Something like <https://go.dev/play/p/wcwHurhNrrC>

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways to improve and accomplish this. I'll start with some improvements, and work my way up to possible implementations of what you're looking for.

### Improvements

First up, I'd avoid using `target interface{}` as an argument. There is absolutely nothing there to guarantee that the caller will pass in a pointer. At the very least, I'd consider using a trick that protobuf uses to ensure arguments of the interface `proto.Message` are pointer values. This is done by adding an empty method with pointer receiver to the types. In this case, that would be:

```
type JSONPtr interface {
    JSONPtr()
}

// implemented:
func (*HelloWorld) JSONPtr() {} // empty

func CensorPayload(target JSONPtr, payload string) (string, error) {
    // pretty much the same as you have here
}
```

Another option would be to use generics, depending on how many types like this you actually need to handle, this could be a valid use-case for them:

```
type CensorTypes interface {
    *HelloWorld | *AnotherType | *YetAnother
}

func CensorPayload[T CensorTypes](target T, payload string) (string, error) {
    // same as what you have now
}
```

#### Reducing duplication with embedding

If you have a number of types with a `Password` field, all of which need to be capable of being censored, you could just split out the `Password` field into its own type and embed it where needed:

```
type Password struct {
    Password string `json:"password"`
}
type HelloWorld struct {
    // regular fields here
    Password // embed the password field
}
```

In case you need to use this password censoring a lot, I'd definitely take this approach. Towards the end, I'll include an example where I use embedded types to accomplish what you're trying to do with minimal code duplication...

### Possible implementations

All this does, however, is ensure that a pointer is passed, which the interface approach already does anyway. You want to be able to censor the password, and have a specific call that does this in your code, so why not implement a method on the relevant types, and add that to an interface. Adding generics, we can get a compile-time check to ensure that the relevant method(s) were implemented correctly (ie with a pointer receiver):

```
type Censored interface {
    *HelloWorld | *AnotherType // and so on
    CensorPass()
}

func (h *HelloWorld) CensorPass() { // pointer receiver
    h.Password = "******"
}
// in case `Password` is an embedded type, no need to implement it on `HelloWorld`
func (p *Password) CensorPass() {
    p.Password = "******"
}

func CenssorPayload[T Censored](target T, payload string) (string, error) {
    // same as before until:
    // Do() is replaced with:
    target.CensorPass()
    // the rest is the same
}
```

Now, if your `HelloWorld` type implements `CensorPass` with a value receiver (`func (h HelloWorld) CensorPass`), or the caller fails to pass in a pointer value as the `target` argument, you'll get an error.

#### Option 2: custom marshallers

Another option here is to create a wrapper type that embeds all of the types you need to handle, and implement a custom marshaller interface on said type:

```
type Wrapper struct {
    *HelloWorld
    *AnotherType
    *YestAnother
}

func (w Wrapper) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    if w.HelloWorld != nil {
        w.HelloWorld.Password = "*****"
        return json.Marshal(w.HelloWorld)
    }
    if w.AnotherType != nil {
        w.AnotherType.Pass = "*****"
        w.AnotherType.AnotherSensitiveField = "*******"
        return json.Marshal(w.AnotherType)
    }
    func w.YetAnother != nil {
        w.YetAnother.User = "<censored>"
        return json.Marshal(w.YetAnother)
    }
}
```

Populating this `Wrapper` type can all be handled by a single function and a type-switch. I'm using `any` (short for `interface{}` below, but I'd recommend you use an interface or generics for the reasons given above if you want to call this method from other packages, if you're calling it from `CensorPayload` alone, and you've already changed it to use interfaces/generics, the code below is fine:

```
func wrap(target any) (*Wrapper, error) {
    switch tt := target.(type) {
    case *HelloWorld:
        return &Wrapper{
            HelloWorld: tt,
        }, nil
    case *AnotherType:
        return &Wrapper{
            AnotherType: tt,
        }, nil
    case *YetAnother:
        return &Wrapper{
            YetAnother: tt,
        }, nil
    }
    // if we reach this point, the type passed to this function is unknown/can't be censored
    return nil, errors.New("type not supported by wrapper")
}
```

With this in place, you can simply change your `CensorPayload` function to something like this:

```
// CensorPayload using interface to ensure pointer argument
func CensorPayload(target JSONPtr, payload string) (string, error) {
     if err := json.Unmarshal(target, []byte(payload)); err != nil {
         return "", err
     }
     wrapped, err := wrap(target)
     if err != nil {
         // type not handled by wrapper, either return an error
         return "", err // target was not supported
         // or in case that means this data should not be censored, just return the marhsalled raw data:
        raw, err := json.Marshal(target)
        if err != nil {
            return "", err
        }
        return string(raw), nil
    }
    raw, err := json.Marshal(wrapped) // this will call Wrapper.MarshalJSON and censor what needs to be censored
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    return string(raw), nil
}
```

#### What I'd go for

I'd probably use the `Censored` type in the `CensorPayload` function. It has the benefit of not needing the wrapper at all, shifts the responsibility of knowing what fields/values to censor on to the data-types, and ensures that both the `CensorPass` method is implemented correctly (pointer receiver), and the actual value being passed is a pointer. To reduce the total LoC to a minimum, I'd leave it to the caller to cast the `[]byte` return value to a string, too. Same goes for the `payload` argument. Raw JSON data is represented as a byte slice, so the `payload`  argument, IMO, should reflect this:

```
func CensorPayload[T Censored](target T, payload []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(target, payload); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    target.CensorPass() // type knows what fields to censor
    return json.Marshal(target) // return the data censored & marshalled
}
```

As mentioned above, I'd combine this approach with commonly censored fields being embedded types:

```
type Password struct {
    Password `json:"password"`
}
type AnotherSensitiveField struct {
    AnotherSensitiveField string `json:"example_db_ip"`
}
// Password implements CensorPass, is embedded so we don't need to do anything here
type HelloWorld struct {
    // fields
    Password
}

// this one has 2 fields that implement CensorPass
// we need to ensure both are called
type AnotherType struct {
    // fields
    Password
    AnotherSensitiveField
}

// this is a one-off, so we need to implement CensorPass on the type
type YetAnother struct {
   // all fields - no password
    User string `json:"user"` // this one needs to be censored
}

func (a *AnotherType) CensorPass() {
    a.Password.CensorPass()
    a.AnotherSensitiveField.CensorPass()
}

func (y *YetAnother) CensorPass() {
    y.User = "<censored>"
}

func (p *Password) CensorPass() {
    p.Password = "******"
}

func (a *AnotherSensitiveField) CensorPass() {
    a.AnotherSensitiveField = "******"
}
```

Any type that embeds one type like `Password` will automatically have a `CensorPass` method. The types are embedded, and no other embedded types have a name collision, so the top level type can resolve `HelloWorld.CensorPass` to `HelloWorld.Password.CensorPass()`. This doesn't work for `AnotherType`, as it has 2 embedded types that provide this method. To get around this, we simply implement the method at the top level, and pass the call on to the embedded types. The third example is one where we want to censor a specific field that isn't used anywhere else (yet). Creating a separate type to embed isn't required, so we can just implement the method directly on the `YetAnother` type. Should we have data where user credentials are present, and we wish to censor multiple fields in different places, we can easily create a type for this:

```
type Credentials struct {
    User string `json:"user"`
    Pass string `json:"pass"`
}
type FullName struct {
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    First string `json:"first_name"`
}

func (c *Credentials) CensorPass() {
    c.User = "<redacted>"
    c.Pass = "******"
}

func (f *FullName) CensorPass() {
    if len(f.First) > 0 {
        f.First = string([]rune(f.First)[0])
    }
    if len(f.Last) == 0 {
        return
    }
    last := make([]string, 0, 2)
    for _, v := range strings.Split(f.Last) {
        if len(v) > 0 {
            last = append(last, string([]rune(v)[0]))
        }
    }
    last = append(last, "") // for the final .
    f.Last = strings.Join(last, ". ") // initials only
}
```

And all we have to do is embed this type wherever we need it. Once that's done, our main function still looks like this:

```
func CensorPayload[T Censored](target T, payload []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    if err := json.Unmarshal(target, payload); err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    target.CensorPass() // type knows what fields to censor
    return json.Marshal(target) // return the data censored & marshalled
}
```

But now, we can add new types to this `Censored` constraint very easily:

```
type Login struct {
    Credentials // username pass
    FullName
}
type Person struct {
    FullName
    Status   string `json:"status"`
}
func (n *NewType) CensorPass() {
    n.Credentials.CensorPass()
    n.FullName.CensorPass()
}
```

With these couple of lines of code, we now have 2 more types that can be passed in to the `CensorPayload` function (by updating the constraint, of course). Given a `Login` and `Person` payload like:

```
// login
{
    "user": "myLogin",
    "pass": "weakpass",
    "name": "Pothering Smythe",
    "first_name": "Emanual",
}
// person
{
    "name": "Doe",
    "first_name": "John",
    "status": "missing",
}
```

We should get the output:

```
{
    "user": "<redacted>",
    "pass": "******",
    "name": "P. S. "
    "first_name": "E",
}
{
    "name": "D. ",
    "first_name": "J",
    "status": "missing",
}
```

#### Note:

I've written all of the code above without testing it out first. There could by typo's and mistakes here and there, but it should contain enough useful information and examples to get you started. If I have some spare time, I'll probably give this a whirl and update the snippets where needed